# How does Kotlin Coroutine's block.startCoroutine() works?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, extension-methods

I was reading the [Coroutine proposal](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/coroutines.md) in [KEEP](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/). And I came across this piece of code in [Coroutine Builders](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/coroutines.md#coroutine-builders) section.

```kotlin
fun launch(context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext, block: suspend () -> Unit) =
    block.startCoroutine(Continuation(context) { result ->
        result.onFailure { exception ->
            val currentThread = Thread.currentThread()
            currentThread.uncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(currentThread, exception)
        }
    })
```

And the [`startCoroutine`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/05896a42da04620a2e8ca35e952ff31c3c48aa9d/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/coroutines/Continuation.kt#L112) is an extension function of a Function Type `(suspend () -> T)`

```kotlin
**
 * Starts a coroutine without a receiver and with result type [T].
 * This function creates and starts a new, fresh instance of suspendable computation every time it is invoked.
 * The [completion] continuation is invoked when the coroutine completes with a result or an exception.
 */
@SinceKotlin("1.3")
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
public fun <T> (suspend () -> T).startCoroutine(
    completion: Continuation<T>
) {
    createCoroutineUnintercepted(completion).intercepted().resume(Unit)
}
```

I am trying to know how the `startCoroutine()` function executes the function it is extending, `block`. Cause I don't see any `this()` here in this code.

The [`createCoroutineUnintercepted()`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/56767592870e03ce916736963a53a243289d213c/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/coroutines/CoroutinesIntrinsicsH.kt#L55) also extends the same Function Type, but there is no source implementation there.

```kotlin
@SinceKotlin("1.3")
public expect fun <T> (suspend () -> T).createCoroutineUnintercepted(
    completion: Continuation<T>
): Continuation<Unit>
```

Asking ChatGPT didn't bring any answers. It says

> When you call `block.startCoroutine(...)`, you're effectively initiating the execution of the block.

Tried to implement a simple Function Type extension [example](https://pl.kotl.in/pmFuwjQqR), but didn't seem to work.

Can anyone please tell me how does this extending function type works?

Does the compiler do any magic here in suspending function regarding this too?

Comment: Away from computer so I can’t check, but is maybe `createCoroutineUnintercepted` an extension function on the same function type?

Comment: It is, but there is no implementation. Editing the question to add details about `createCoroutineUnintercepted`

Comment: It’s an `expect` function. That keyword is usually used for multiplatform code where you implement it differently for each platform. But in this case I think they’re using it because the implementation is “compiler magic”.

Comment: I did not see the `expect` keyword there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to know how the startCoroutine() function executes the function it is extending, block. Cause I don't see any this() here in this code.

Remember that `this` is implicitly in the context throughout the body of the function, so any call to functions or properties (including extensions) of the type of `this` can be done without specifying `this.`. So in practice the implementation of `startCoroutine()` is as if `this.` was written:

```kotlin
public fun <T> (suspend () -> T).startCoroutine(
    completion: Continuation<T>
) {
    this.createCoroutineUnintercepted(completion).intercepted().resume(Unit)
}
```

So as you can see the `(suspend () -> T)` receiver is simply passed on to `createCoroutineUnintercepted` (because as you noted it does have the same receiver type). Now, of course this just pushes the problem down to that other function.

> but there is no source implementation there.

In fact, both `createCoroutineUnintercepted` and `suspendCoroutineUninterceptedOrReturn` are special functions recognized and transformed by the Kotlin compiler (called *intrinsics*). This is why they are in the [`kotlin.coroutines.intrinsics` package](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.intrinsics/). They are the basic building blocks provided by the language in order for more user-friendly frameworks (such as the Kotlinx Coroutines library) to be built.

I recommend this blog post to understand what the basic language primitives are and how we can build a framework like Kotlinx Coroutines from them:
https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/kotlin-coroutines-animated-part-1-coroutine-hello-world-51797d8b9cd4

In addition to the coroutines' KEEP, you might find this detailed technical document useful too:
https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/backend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/codegen/coroutines/coroutines-codegen.md

> Tried to implement a simple Function Type extension example, but didn't seem to work.

About this, you simply printed `this` (using the `$this` template syntax), but you didn't *call* it. You can add parentheses to your code to make it work (and for this, you'll need to add braces in your string template). So, simply replace `$this` with `${this()}` and it will in fact call it and print what you expect:

```kotlin
inline fun (() -> Int).start() {
    println("start received ${this()}")
}

fun launch(block: () -> Int) {
    block.start()
}

fun main() {
    launch {
        1
    }
}
```

Comment: about printing `$this`, it was to see whether the function type is executed or just is received as Function Object, cause according to Big brother ChatGPT it is executed :P

Comment: ChatGPT is wrong too often to be trusted. However, to its defense, it was specifically answering about `block.startCoroutine()`, which technically does execute the receiver at some point